# UINavigationBar back button crashing the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

When I run my app in simulator everything is fine, but when I run in device it is crashing.

Reason is I am pushing one xib from my storyboard and it's working well but when I press the back button it is crashing and `[myxib class name method]`  message sent to deallocated instance 0x1fc65600. But in simulator it's fine, is that due to memory leak?

It is pointing to:

```
0x311ad468  trap   <--- Thread1:EXC_BREAKPOINT (code =EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT ,subcode=0xdefe))      

[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:obj animated:YES];
```

Comment: give code from back button and push method

Answer (score -1):

I solved it,first thing is iam retrieving some values in previous class from someother class,so when iam out of focus that value transaction is throwing exception,so what i done is i disable the back button for  some seconds

Comment: I read your answer but I have trouble understanding what you mean.